# Refactor toPredicate method of JPA to support Java 7 and 8

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I've done some coding with the use of `toPredicate()` method now I want to refactor it so that I can use it in `Java 7` also.

I've posted below some sample code which I've done so far.

**EntitySpecification.java**

```java
public class EntitySpecification {

    public static Specification<MyEntity> textInAllColumns(String text) {

        if (!text.contains("%")) {
            text = "%"+text+"%";
        }
        final String finalText = text;

        return new Specification<MyEntity>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                return builder.or(root.getModel().getDeclaredSingularAttributes().stream().filter(a-> {
                    if (a.getJavaType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                }}).map(a -> builder.like(root.get(a.getName()), finalText)
                    ).toArray(Predicate[]::new)
                );
            }
        };
    }

 }
```

Comment: Replace the lambda expressions with anonymous classes. If you are using an IDE like IntelliJ it can do it for you.

Comment: Idea: research the term **lambda expression**.

Comment: And just for the record: just dropping requirements here "this is what I need" ... without showing any evidence that you tried to work on your problem yourself isn't exactly appreciated. You also learn **much** more when you try to first problems yourself. Asking others for help is something that you do *later*, when you are pretty convinced that you are unable to make more progress yourself. You see, in the end, you **own** that code. Does it really help you when others drop code on you, but you don't know what that code is doing?!

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for your suggestion. I will work on that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda expressions (`->`) came with Java 8. In order to use the code in Java 7 you have to replace them with anonymous classes.
If you use and IDE like IntelliJ it can do the job for you. Move the cursor to the `->` and then hit `ALT + ENTER`. A popup window should show up and there should be an option to `Replace lambda with anonymous class`.

```java
.filter(a -> {
    if (a.getJavaType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
})
```

to

```java
.filter(new java.util.function.Predicate<SingularAttribute<MyEntity, ?>>() {
  @Override
  public boolean test(SingularAttribute<MyEntity, ?> a) {
      if (a.getJavaType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }
})
```

Also you have to get rid of everything you are using from the `java.util.function` package.

You can replace the `.filter()` with a for loop and an if statement inside of it. For the `.map()` you have to modify the previously filtered collection with a for loop.

```java
new Specification<MyEntity>() {
  @Override
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
      List<SingularAttribute<MyEntity, ?>> tempAttributes = new ArrayList<>();
      for (SingularAttribute<MyEntity, ?> attribute : root.getModel().getDeclaredSingularAttributes()) {
          if (attribute.getJavaType().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
              tempAttributes.add(attribute);
          }
      }

      final Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[tempAttributes.size()];

      for (int i = 0; i < tempAttributes.size(); i++) {
          predicates[i] = builder.like(root.<MyEntity>get(tempAttributes.get(i).getName()), finalText);
      }

      return builder.or(predicates);
  }
};
```

I didn't tried it myself but this should work or at least give you the first steps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace

```
- stream
- filter
- map
```

because there is no Streaming API in Java 7.

By replace I mean you have to loop over getDeclaredSingularAttributes() and the filter the elements and map it.

Also `Predicate[]::new` has to be replaced by `new Predicate[]` because there are now method references.

As Rashin said this can be done with the IDE if you set the source level to Java 7 it will provide help.

Comment: Not so sure about the last sentence. Well, that should tell you which syntax constructs aren't supported. It doesnt help with stream library stuff, as long as you don't point the whole project to a Java 7 JDK.

Comment: At least IntelliJ has the option "Replace Stream API chain with loop" and this works great. NetBeans also has a similar option to move from and to Stream API. But I'm not sure about Eclipse